# 3D-Highchart Dynamic Series Add issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, highcharts

I'm learning the 3d-highchars , i have small issues when dynamically add the series.

The series is not load proper place, that is second "stack:1" is loading the "stack:0" position.

I have added below snippet code check and let me know this issue.
[Click the "click me" button to generate the chart]

Thanks in advance !!

```js
var chart;

$(function () {
    // Set up the chart
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        
        chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container', type: 'column',
                    options3d: { enabled: true, alpha: 25, beta: 25, viewDistance: 25, depth: 40 },
                    marginTop: 80, marginRight: 40
                },
                plotOptions: { column: { depth: 40, stacking: true, grouping: false } },
        series: []
    });
    
    $('#clickMe').on('click', function () {
        var odata=[{data: [1,5,3,6,2],stack: 0},
                {data: [7,7,9,8,6],stack: 1}];
        
        $.each(odata, function (itemNo, item) {
                chart.addSeries({
                    data: item.data,
                    stack: item.stack
                }, false);
        });
        chart.redraw();
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
<button id="clickMe">Click Me</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember as per the [documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/3d-charts)
`You will need at least the following depth: number of columns * (depth of column + z-padding)`. So here is a updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1rjfy1za/) that solves your problem by increasing `depth` and you can modify it based on your onClick function!

```
 chart: {
            type: 'column',
            margin: 75,
            options3d: {
                enabled: true,
                alpha: 25,
                beta: 25,
                viewDistance: 25,
                depth: 110
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                depth: 40,
                stacking: true,
                grouping: false,
                groupZPadding: 10
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks prem, i wont change depth and all , i did small change its working perfect http://jsfiddle.net/logukrp/kxn2b0w6/  working link :)